# Determinant of a matrix of order n

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = [aij ]$ be a square matrix of order $n$ whose entries are given as follows. For $1\leq i,j \leq n$ we have
$$a_{ij} = \begin{cases}
    ij\quad,&i\neq j\\
    1+ij\quad, & i=j
\end{cases}$$
Evaluate the determinant of $A$.

I would like to know if there is a way to evaluate without explicitly calculating.

Comment: The determinants should be given by [OEIS A056520](https://oeis.org/A056520): $|A_n|=\frac{(n+2)(2n^2-n+3)}6$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider the $n\times n$ matrix $B$ with $b_{ij}=ij$ for all $i,j$.  For every $j$, the $j$th row of $B$ is $j$ times the first row.  So row-reducing $B$ gives $n-1$ zero rows, so $B$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ with algebraic multiplicity at least $n-1$.  The $n$th eigenvalue is therefore
$$\lambda_n=trace(B)=1^2+\cdots+n^2=\tfrac16n(n+1)(2n+1)\ .$$
Hence
$$\eqalign{\det(B-\lambda I)
  &=(\lambda_1-\lambda)\cdots(\lambda_n-\lambda)=(-\lambda)^{n-1}(\lambda_n-\lambda)\ .\cr}$$
Your matrix $A$ is $B+I$, so substituting $\lambda=-1$ gives
$$\det(A)=\det(B+I)=\lambda_n+1=\tfrac16n(n+1)(2n+1)+1\ .$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Let $b=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & \ldots & n \end{bmatrix}^T$ and $B=bb^T$, then we have

$$A=I+B$$

Hence your goal is to compute $(I+B)^{-1}$, you might like to use [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Comment: @ Siong Thye Goh : Thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score 2):

Write $A=I+B$ where $B=v^Tv$ and $v$ is the row vector $\pmatrix{1&2&3&\cdots&n}$.
Then $B$ has rank $1$ and $B^2=v^Tvv^Tv=NB$ where $N=vv^T=1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2$.
(I'm sure you must know the closed formula for that). The eigenvalues
of $A=B+I$ are then $N+1$ with multiplicity $1$ and $1$ with multiplicity
$n-1$. Therefore
$$\det A=N+1=1+\sum_{k=1}^n k^2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. @Lord Shark the Unknown